# VIM: Change working directory only for the current buffer

Tags: vim

How can I change a current working directory for a specific buffer and change it to a previous value for other buffers?

More precisely what I want to do is to have auto-commands for specific file types which will change a current working directory when a buffer containing the file type is active. And change it back when working with other buffers.

I had something like that in my vimrc:

```
autocmd BufEnter *.py :lcd%:p:h
autocmd BufLeave *.py :lcd-
```

The idea here is that I wanted to switch to file's directory when working on python files and switch to a previous directory when working on something else, e.g. text, vimL etc. Obviously, it didn't work. I also try using `BufWinLeave`, but it didn't change anything.

Can you point out what's wrong here? Or maybe there's an easier solution for that?

Comment: If `:lcd` affects only the *.py files then why would you even try to revert the CWD for other buffers?! What are you reverting to if the CWD of that buffer never changed?

Comment: Note that `:lcd` is window-local, not buffer-local.

Comment: @work.bin as romainl mentioned window-local, not buffer- or file-local. In the same window I can have several buffers of different file types. And I want cwd to be the same for all buffers, except for .py files, there I want to change CWD to the dir containing a .py file.

Comment: I use tabbed Gvim, so I have never faced this problem. For me a buffer and tab are practically the same thing. And :lcd is definitely tab-local.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could accomplish something similar with the following:

```
augroup CDRooter
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinEnter * if &filetype == 'python' | lcd %:p:h | else | lcd! | endif
augroup END
```

Note: I am not sure `:lcd -` will work well. Instead I use `:lcd!` to simply revert the window to using the global current working directory.

The basic idea is whenever you enter a window sniff the filetype and execute `:lcd` accordingly.

For more help see:

```
:h 'filetype'
:h BufWinEnter
:h :lcd
:h :augroup
:h :autocmd
:h :if
```

Comment: That doesn't really work. It does work as expected, but it's not what I wanted. I don't want to go to home directory, I wanted to go to the directory where a file (other than .py) was opened. `:lcd -` does work fine when I try it manually. But in auto-command from my question it doesn't, it seems like cwd is changed several times to the same dir, because`lcd -` returns the same directory (enclosing the python file).

Comment: @mfedoten I have changed to using `:lcd!` to use the global current work directory for non-python windows. This may not be what you want. You may want to use `:lcd` for some specific non-python buffers. If that is the case you would probably need some mechanism to store the correct directory in a buffer variable and use it to `:lcd` to the correct directory. Or rely on some command to re-`:lcd` to the proper location (e.g. fugitive.vim's `:Glcd`)